# Vaadin Icon and Label not in one Row using Horizontal Layout

Tags: java, vaadin

i try to get the Icon and the Label in one Row, but the icon is a little bit higher.

This was my try:

```
  private VerticalLayout createActiveProductsCard() {
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setWidth("50px");
    layout.setHeight("150px");
    layout.getStyle().set("margin-bottom","20px");
    layout.getStyle().set("border", "0.5px solid #9E9E9E");

    Icon icon = new Icon(VaadinIcon.BARCODE);
    icon.setSize("20px");
    Label title = new Label("Produkte");
    title.getStyle().set("font-size","20px");
    HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout(icon, title);
    horizontalLayout.setVerticalComponentAlignment(Alignment.AUTO);
    layout.add(horizontalLayout);
    return layout;
}
```

But it wont work, does anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Alignment.CENTER` instead of `Alignment.AUTO`, and enclose the `Label` in a `Div`. Here's an example:

```
Icon icon = new Icon(VaadinIcon.BARCODE);
icon.setSize("20px");
Div title = new Div(new Label("Produkte"));
title.getStyle().set("font-size","20px");
HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout(icon, title);
horizontalLayout.setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
layout.add(horizontalLayout);
```

Comment: Though, avoid using fixed sizes and inline styles when you can. It will make it easier to keep styling consistent and easier to maintain. One step to improve is to use CSS custom properties, for example, the ones the default Lumo theme offers.